Синонимизировать метки [webbrowser] и [браузер]
Предлагаю синонимизировать сетки

webbrowser (301)
браузер (422)

описание у обеих есть - надо будет выбрать, какое получше
Основная - браузер, так как она на русском.

webbrowser - это имя стандартного модуля в Python. Придется поменять метку везде, где используется этот модуль, на python-webbrowser.

Ну такое, не согласен с итоговым решением.

@insolor, вопросы о python-webbrowser в конечном счёте в основном про браузеры ;)

Вопросы о python-webbrowser в конечном счете про запуск браузера из Python. В каком-нибудь C# - про класс WebBrowser. И в итоге все не глядя тупо слили в одну кучу на мета-метку.

@insolor на enSO есть выделенные метки для шарпов/дотнета и питона — [webbrowser-control] и [python-webbrowser] соответственно, если я не ошибаюсь. И нам бы стоит тоже завести подобные. В этом случае вопросы всё равно надо переразметить и слияние меток в этом плане не должно быть проблемой. При этом старые метки [браузер] и [webbrowser] имели схожее описание, т.е. если их использовали для случаев питона/шарпов — значит их использовали не совсем корректно.

@αλεχολυτ, ок, тогда согласен.

Готово!
updating post history, 287 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 301 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 282 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'webbrowser': [webbrowser] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 724
tag remapping of [браузер] and [webbrowser] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
7 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym webbrowser -> браузер was approved!

